# Image View VS UIImage View Xcode placement

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I have just started making IOS apps in swift. In all tutorials people drag an Image view to the view controller and it automatically calls itself a UIImageView and fills the whole screen.

When I drag the image view over, it names itself Image View, and will never fill the whole screen. Does anyone know how to make my xcode act like theirs?

tutorial in question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eP_xW-Zz34

**MORE INFO (not necessary):**

Then as I follow tutorials (made in July 2015ish) the code never compiles when I do it just the way they do it (minus the UIImage vs image). There's always a few things off.

Did ios just switch to a new version of swift/xcode that makes all these tutorials obsolete or is there some code setting that I need to change to make the code work.

**More specific code differences and emerging errors**

Their code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    // Create a place to render the filtered image
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    @IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

        // Create an image to filter
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)

        // Create a random color to pass to a filter
        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

        // Apply a filter to the image
        let filteredImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

        // Render the filtered image
        let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent())

        // Reflect the change back in the interface
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Error I get from that code:

```
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)
```

Gives the error: `Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

The reason I include this code and the error is because I think it is tied to the difference in xcode's behavior with Image Views and may help pinpoint the cause of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is photoImageView.image return an UIImage, that is an optional variable in Swift, with the current code the Xcode will cry that warning.
You can do one of these:

Force casting:

```
let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!)
```

or put some guaranty checking before:

```
guard let img = photoImageView.image else { return }
let inputImage = CIImage(image: img)
```

Note: Xcode 7, Swift 2.*

Comment: Xcode does recommend that fix, but that code error was really a 2ndary point added onto the initial question of, is my xcode different and if so can I make it not.

Comment: Sure your xCode is different with the instruction's version. You know, Swift compiler is still evolving, that make some code is good on old compiler but not on new compiler.